# mysql user defined function always return true

Tags: mysql

I have created mysql function to check if record exists then return true else false but given function always return true. Not sure why and where we have mistake. Any one suggest please.

```
CREATE DEFINER =  `hugosys`@`localhost` FUNCTION  `GetUserFeedLike` (
`userFeedID` INT,
`userID` INT
) RETURNS BOOLEAN NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN DECLARE flag BOOL DEFAULT FALSE ;

SELECT EXISTS (

SELECT * 
FROM userFeedLikes
WHERE userFeedID = userFeedID
AND userID = userID
)
INTO flag;

RETURN flag;

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a confusion between parameters and columns.  *Always* give parameters distinctive names:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetUserFeedLike (
    in_userFeedID INT,
    in_userID` INT
) RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_flag BOOL; DEFAULT FALSE ;

    SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM userFeedLikes
                   WHERE userFeedID = in_userFeedID AND userID = in_userID
                  )
    INTO v_flag;

    RETURN v_flag;
END;
```

When you write:

```
WHERE userFeedID = userFeedID AND userID = userID
```

You are just comparing the column to itself.

Comment: Yes, Got it, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You comparing the columns with themselves, hence it return true.

Change your variable names to something bit different like prefixing a `p_` to denote a parameter.

```
CREATE DEFINER =  `hugosys`@`localhost` FUNCTION  `GetUserFeedLike` (
`p_userFeedID` INT,
`p_userID` INT
) RETURNS BOOLEAN NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN DECLARE flag BOOL DEFAULT FALSE ;

SELECT EXISTS (

SELECT * 
FROM userFeedLikes
WHERE userFeedID = `p_userFeedID`
AND userID = `p_userID`
)
INTO flag;

RETURN flag;

END
```

Comment: Yes, Got it, Thank you